# Split string with regex group

Tags: ruby, string, split

I get the following output when I use `split` with regex on a string.

```
string = "12345678"

string.split(/(..)/)

=> ["", "12", "", "34", "", "56", "", "78"]
```

Why am I getting empty strings from the `split` method? I realize that using the `scan` method would give me pairs without the empty strings, but I want to know *why* `split` is giving me empty strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is not a duplicate. Read the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The linked question solves how to get the result I wanted. I wanted to know *why* it was giving me empty strings.

Comment: Ok, I see it is difficult to find another original question. Let's keep this one.

Comment: So, now it is OK to ask two questions: "how can I solve it" and "why does my code fail"? It just feels illogical, I would "merge" both into one. If you know any meta post that discusses it, please share.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I see what you mean. I will edit my question to be more focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the initial empty string, it is because the original purpose of `split` is to delimit a string into fields with a delimiter. It always assumes that there is a field before a delimiter, even if it is empty. As for the other empty strings, it is because the delimiters are adjacent.